# A Funny-Looking Sign Off on Television (Test Pattern Generator Image)

Tags: telecommunications

I came across this display on television while I visited the island of Mindanao in the Philippines in November 3, 2017. I thought this might be a sign-off display from a TV network, but I noticed that it shows the same display all day.

It looks like this:

[image]

Getting closer:

[image]

I thought that sign-off display for many TV networks in the Philippines look like this: A vertical strips of color with some identification of TV network

Example would be

[image]

My question is:

**In the first two photos....what are those display?**

Comment: It's a test pattern as winny stated. It was also [popular in Turkey](http://www.kameraarkasi.org/tv/ayar/trt_02.jpg) for almost 30 years. Besides, if you turn the volume up, you'll hear a 1 kHz test sound.

Comment: @RohatKılıç interesting.....

Comment: Also [popular in Norway](https://mediehistorie.wikispaces.com/file/view/nrk.jpg/34233453/348x279/nrk.jpg). My guess is that this pattern has been used in most [PAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL) regions at some point over the years.

Comment: In a properly-adjusted television, that ellipse should be **round**. This image is one with a wide aspect ratio, which means that everything in it will be wider than normal. People's faces aren't really that fat...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a standard Philips PM5544 test pattern generator image. Used by many TV stations all over the world. It could be considered part of pop culture too due to this.

[image][image]

[image][image]

Comment: That's what I call "electronic arts" :-)

Comment: Nice. [This](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/RCA_Indian_Head_test_pattern.png) is the B&W test pattern I remember from long ago in North America.

Comment: Hi winny. Do you own the PM5544 signal generator in the photo? Did you take the photo by yourself and own its copyright? This machine is an important artifact of popular culture, yet photos of the signal generator itself is uncommon on the web (and many people mistakenly believed the PM5544 is just a test card, not a signal generator). I'd like to find a high-quality photo of the PM5544 under a free license and add it to Wikipedia, and your photo is an excellent candidate.

Comment: @比尔盖子 Sorry, no. I "borrowed" it. Happy hunting!

Comment: @winny Thanks for responding. Well, it's strange because I couldn't find the source of your photo anywhere on the web (did it also go down? Too bad...) so I assumed you were the photographer. I'll keep hunting...

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, it is a test pattern.

I remember this one from the UK that was introduced in 1967 after color TVs became the norm.

[image]

These patterns used to be used frequently during "dead air" times. Once upon a time before god or whomever invented reruns and automated broadcasting, TV and radio stations shut down during off-peak hours. Basically, everyone went home. In the mean time, they broadcast the signal that produced these patterns. It could even pop up in between programs. In some regions, and on some stations in the dead of night, the test pattern is still used.

The patterns themselves were not just random though.

They are designed to allow a knowledgeable TV owner, or another extinct beast.. "The TV Repair Man" to "adjust the set". The back of TVs used to be festooned with pots that let you adjust pretty much everything. If also helps the engineers that maintained the broadcast system itself to have a consistent signal broadcasting 24/7.

[image]

The test pattern let you see the results of those adjustments. Note: The girl, [Carole Hersee](https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/667462/Test-Card-Girl-Carole-Hersee-now), and her pet toy were added so you could adjust the color to get the skin tones "right".

Comment: For more Carole Hersee, I would recommend the excellent TV series Life on Mars where she comes alive and steps out of the TV set.